# Generating means of combinations in multiindex dataframe (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a multiindexed dataframe where the index levels have multiple categories, something like this:

```
                     |Var1|Var2|Var3|
|Level1|Level2|Level3|----|----|----|
|  A   |  A   |   A  |    |    |    |
|  A   |  A   |   B  |    |    |    |
|  A   |  B   |   A  |    |    |    |
|  A   |  B   |   B  |    |    |    |
|  B   |  A   |   A  |    |    |    |
|  B   |  A   |   B  |    |    |    |
|  B   |  B   |   A  |    |    |    |
|  B   |  B   |   B  |    |    |    |
```

In summary, and specifically in my case, Level 1 has 2 levels, Level 2 has 24, Level 3 has 6, and there are also Levels 4 (674) and Level 5 (9) (with some minor variation depending on specific higher-level values - `Level1 == 1` actually has 24 Level2s, but `Level1 == 2` has 23).

I need to generate all possible combinations of 3 at Level 5, then calculate their means for Vars 1-3.

I am trying something like this:

```
# Resulting df to be populated
df_result = pd.DataFrame([])
# Retrieving values at Level1
lev1s = df.index.get_level_values("Level1").unique()
# Looping through each Level1 value
for lev1 in lev1s:
   # Filtering df based on Level1 value
   df_lev1 = df.query('Level1 == ' + str(lev1))
   # Repeating...
   lev2s = df_lev1.index.get_level_values("Level2").unique()
   for lev2 in lev2s:
      df_lev2 = df_lev1.query('Level2 == ' + str(lev2))
      # ... until Level3
      lev3s = df_lev2.index.get_level_values("Level3").unique()
      # Creating all combinations
      combs = itertools.combinations(lev3s, 3)
      # Looping through each combination
      for comb in combs:
         # Filtering values in combination
         df_comb = df_wl.query('Level3 in ' + str(comb))
         # Calculating means using groupby (groupby might not be necessary, 
         # but I don't believe it has much of an impact
         df_means = df_comb.reset_index().groupby(['Level1', 'Level2']).mean()
         # Extending resulting dataframe
         df_result = df_result.append(df_means)
```

The thing is, after a little while, this process gets really slow. Since I have around 2 * 24 * 6 * 674 levels and 84 combinations (of 9 elements, 3 by 3), I am expecting more than 16 million `df_means`s to be calculated.

Is there any more efficient way to do this?

Thank you.